# Reduce the four views to only two (1st and 3rd person)

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I am playing GTA V on PC via Steam, with my XBOX 360 wireless gamepad. To switch between views, I press the select-button, which cycles between 1st person and three kinds of 3rd person (with three different distances between camera and character).
Now I find it pretty annoying if I want to quickly switch petween 1st and 3rd person, I often have to press the button three times.

I would like to edit some config file so there's only two views available, one 1st and one 3rd person, so I can alway switch directly between those. Is this possible?

I know it sounds silly, but sometimes I switch the view a lot to play around, and it's really annoying for me.

Answer (score 1):

What you want isn't directly available in the game but I'd recommend using autohotkey etc. to press select 3 times when you are in third person and one time in first person. I will not provide example code.

Comment: That is indeed a nice solution. I will give autohotkey a try and write a script the next days. Will post it if it works as wanted :)